# routing between vlans not working

Tags: routing, router, vlan, nat, cisco-ios

I need to put a Cisco router behind an ISP router.
(The ISP doesn't allow us to use their modem only.)

I've called the ISP technical service and they've set up the connection with me.
Their router will be used as a gateway for the Cisco router.
I configured vlan20 with the correct IP address and linked it to Ge0, which is connected to the ISP router. I can ping the internet from that VLAN.

I also created vlan10 for the internal network, which will be connected to Ge1.
From that vlan, I'm not able to ping the internet.

I tried to configure a gateway of last resort but that didn't work.

Below is an overview of the setup/configuration:
[image]

```
interface GigabitEthernet0
 switchport access vlan 20
 no ip address

interface GigabitEthernet1
 switchport access vlan 10
 no ip address

interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.9.200.253 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1412

interface Vlan20
 ip address 81.246.66.67 255.255.255.

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 81.246.66.66
```

I thought it would work with that route to the ISP router, but it seems it doesn't work:
[image]
Could anyone provide me some help with this?

Edit: full config as requested:
Only hidden some passwords and changed the public IP's.

```
R1#show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 11179 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 19:24:21 GMT Thu Jul 12 2018
! NVRAM config last updated at 19:39:43 GMT Thu Jul 12 2018
! NVRAM config last updated at 19:39:43 GMT Thu Jul 12 2018
version 15.3
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
aqm-register-fnf
!
logging buffered 51200 warnings
enable secret 5 --hash hidden--.
!
no aaa new-model
wan mode ethernet
clock timezone GMT 1 0
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.9.200.253
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.9.200.0 192.9.200.130
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.9.200.169 192.9.200.210
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.9.200.250 192.9.200.255
!
ip dhcp pool ccp-pool
 import all
 network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.128
 default-router 10.10.10.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8 195.238.2.21
 lease 0 2
!
ip dhcp pool companyname_dhcp_pool
 import all
 network 192.9.200.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.9.200.253
 dns-server 192.9.200.253
 domain-name dw
 lease 0 2
!
!
!
ip domain name companyname.be
ip host kassa1.companyname.be 192.9.200.40
ip host kassa2.companyname.be 192.9.200.41
ip host www.companyname.be. 81.246.66.67
ip host bkhserv.companyname.be. 192.9.200.3
ip host pcroland.companyname.be. 192.9.200.4
ip host pckarel.companyname.be. 192.9.200.6
ip host achtertoog.companyname.be. 192.9.200.9
ip host verkopersbalie2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.11
ip host voortoog1.companyname.be. 192.9.200.12
ip host voortoog2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.13
ip host geertje.companyname.be. 192.9.200.14
ip host verkopersbalie.companyname.be. 192.9.200.15
ip host hobbytoog.companyname.be. 192.9.200.17
ip host houtenvloer.companyname.be. 192.9.200.25
ip host pinnerij.companyname.be. 192.9.200.26
ip host annmarina.companyname.be. 192.9.200.27
ip host pp1.companyname.be. 192.9.200.28
ip host ppuitsnij.companyname.be. 192.9.200.29
ip host pcglas.companyname.be. 192.9.200.32
ip host pczagerij.companyname.be. 192.9.200.36
ip host kassa1.companyname.be. 192.9.200.40
ip host kassa2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.41
ip host kassa3.companyname.be. 192.9.200.42
ip host kassa4.companyname.be. 192.9.200.43
ip host metapacekassa1.companyname.be. 192.9.200.50
ip host metapacekassa2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.51
ip host metapacekassa3.companyname.be. 192.9.200.52
ip host bijdoen.companyname.be. 192.9.200.57
ip host wim.companyname.be. 192.9.200.61
ip host erwin.companyname.be. 192.9.200.62
ip host christiane.companyname.be. 192.9.200.63
ip host anna.companyname.be. 192.9.200.64
ip host afplak.companyname.be. 192.9.200.65
ip host christine.companyname.be. 192.9.200.66
ip host alu.companyname.be. 192.9.200.67
ip host peter.companyname.be. 192.9.200.68
ip host herman.companyname.be. 192.9.200.69
ip host iomegaix2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.85
ip host pcguy.companyname.be. 192.9.200.87
ip host pc-jan.companyname.be. 192.9.200.88
ip host mailserver.companyname.be. 192.9.200.90
ip host pcjan.companyname.be. 192.9.200.91
ip host TerminalServer.companyname.be. 192.9.200.94
ip host scovmwar.companyname.be. 192.9.200.95
ip host scovm2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.96
ip host linksyswap54g.companyname.be. 192.9.200.98
ip host supmicro.companyname.be. 192.9.200.100
ip host hpnet.companyname.be. 192.9.200.96
ip host faxverkoop.companyname.be. 192.9.200.101
ip host faxjan.companyname.be. 192.9.200.102
ip host hpc6180.companyname.be. 192.9.200.103
ip host hpclj4600.companyname.be. 192.9.200.104
ip host hp4000.companyname.be. 192.9.200.106
ip host hp4achttoog.companyname.be. 192.9.200.107
ip host hp4voortoog.companyname.be. 192.9.200.108
ip host hp4chret.companyname.be. 192.9.200.109
ip host hp4karel.companyname.be. 192.9.200.110
ip host hp4verkoop.companyname.be. 192.9.200.111
ip host hp4kassa3.companyname.be. 192.9.200.112
ip host hp4posters.companyname.be. 192.9.200.113
ip host hp4prod1.companyname.be. 192.9.200.114
ip host hp4prod2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.115
ip host hp4repros.companyname.be. 192.9.200.116
ip host hp4kassa1.companyname.be. 192.9.200.117
ip host hp4aankoop.companyname.be. 192.9.200.120
ip host hp4klaarpak.companyname.be. 192.9.200.121
ip host hp4kassa2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.122
ip host hp4infopapier.companyname.be. 192.9.200.124
ip host hp4infoverf.companyname.be. 192.9.200.125
ip host bkhservdw.companyname.be. 192.9.200.170
ip host dell.companyname.be. 192.9.200.170
ip host companynamets.companyname.be. 192.9.200.200
ip host firewall.companyname.be. 192.9.200.253
ip host houtenvloer2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.24
ip host wegzet.companyname.be. 192.9.200.49
ip host linksyswap54g2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.97
ip host telcentrale1.companyname.be. 192.9.200.75
ip host telcentrale2.companyname.be. 192.9.200.76
ip host zebra01.companyname.be. 192.9.200.118
ip host esxtest.companyname.be. 192.9.200.167
ip host xenserver.companyname.be. 192.9.200.174
ip host odooserver-xen.companyname.be. 192.9.200.168
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip name-server 195.238.2.21
ip name-server 4.4.4.4
ip name-server 195.238.2.22
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
flow record nbar-appmon
 match ipv4 source address
 match ipv4 destination address
 match application name
 collect interface output
 collect counter bytes
 collect counter packets
 collect timestamp absolute first
 collect timestamp absolute last
!
!
flow monitor application-mon
 cache timeout active 60
 record nbar-appmon
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
object-group network local_lan_subnets
 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.128
 192.9.200.0 255.255.255.0
!
username companyname privilege 15 secret 5 --hash hidden--
!
!
controller VDSL 0
 shutdown
!
zone security LAN
zone security WAN
zone security VPN
zone security DMZ
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface ATM0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 no atm ilmi-keepalive
!
interface Ethernet0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0
 no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet1
 no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet2
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0
 switchport access vlan 20
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 switchport access vlan 10
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet2
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Wlan-GigabitEthernet0
 description Internal switch interface connecting to the embedded AP
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan1
 description $ETH_LAN$
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.128
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1412
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.9.200.253 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1412
!
interface Vlan20
 ip address 81.246.66.67 255.255.255.248
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip http server
ip http access-class 23
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip http timeout-policy idle 60 life 86400 requests 10000
!
!
ip dns server
ip nat inside source list nat-list interface GigabitEthernet2 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 25 81.246.66.67 25 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.175 80 81.246.66.67 80 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 110 81.246.66.67 110 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 143 81.246.66.67 143 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.9.200.90 143 81.246.66.67 143 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 25 81.246.66.67 587 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.94 6666 81.246.66.67 3389 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 80 81.246.66.68 80 extendable
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet2
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 81.246.66.66
!
dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
!
access-list 23 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.127
access-list 23 permit 192.9.200.0 0.0.0.255
!
banner exec ^C
% Password expiration warning.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Cisco Configuration Professional (Cisco CP) is installed on this device
and it provides the default username "cisco" for  one-time use. If you have
already used the username "cisco" to login to the router and your IOS image
supports the "one-time" user option, then this username has already expired.
You will not be able to login to the router with this username after you exit
this session.

It is strongly suggested that you create a new username with a privilege level
of 15 using the following command.

username <myuser> privilege 15 secret 0 <mypassword>

Replace <myuser> and <mypassword> with the username and password you
want to use.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
^C
banner login ^C
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Cisco Configuration Professional (Cisco CP) is installed on this device.
This feature requires the one-time use of the username "cisco" with the
password "cisco". These default credentials have a privilege level of 15.

YOU MUST USE CISCO CP or the CISCO IOS CLI TO CHANGE THESE
PUBLICLY-KNOWN CREDENTIALS

Here are the Cisco IOS commands.

username <myuser>  privilege 15 secret 0 <mypassword>
no username cisco

Replace <myuser> and <mypassword> with the username and password you want
to use.

IF YOU DO NOT CHANGE THE PUBLICLY-KNOWN CREDENTIALS, YOU WILL
NOT BE ABLE TO LOG INTO THE DEVICE AGAIN AFTER YOU HAVE LOGGED OFF.

For more information about Cisco CP please follow the instructions in the
QUICK START GUIDE for your router or go to http://www.cisco.com/go/ciscocp
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
^C
!
line con 0
 password -- PW hidden --
 login
 no modem enable
line aux 0
line 2
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport input all
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 access-class 23 in
 privilege level 15
 password -- PW hidden --
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
scheduler allocate 60000 1000
ntp master
ntp server europe.pool.ntp.org
!
end
```

**Update: It's working now, the fault was misconfiguration of NAT indeed.**
This is the extra configuration I've done:

```
ip nat inside source list nat-list interface Vlan20 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 25 81.246.66.67 25 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.175 80 81.246.66.67 80 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 110 81.246.66.67 110 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 81.246.66.67 143 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.9.200.90 81.246.66.67 143 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 25 81.246.66.67 587 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.94 6666 81.246.66.67 3389 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.9.200.90 80 81.246.66.68 80 extendable
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 81.246.66.66
!
ip access-list extended nat-list
 deny   ip 192.9.200.0 0.0.0.255 host 192.9.200.90
 deny   ip 192.9.200.0 0.0.0.255 host 192.9.200.175
 deny   ip 192.9.200.0 0.0.0.255 host 192.9.200.94
 permit tcp any any
 permit udp any any
 permit icmp any any
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full router configuration. What you have is incomplete, and we cannot see your NAT configuration or any configurations where you may have made a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you have not defined the ACL that tells the router which addresses to translate.

You have:

```
ip nat inside source list nat-list interface GigabitEthernet2 overload
```

but you do not have the `nat-list` configured. You need something like:

```
access-list nat-list permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.127
access-list nat-list permit 192.9.200.0 0.0.0.255
```

-or-

use the ACL (23) you did define for NAT:

```
ip nat inside source list 23 interface GigabitEthernet2 overload
```

-and-

As Ron Trunk pointed out, place the `ip nat outside` command on the WAN interface.

Comment: Thanks, it indeed makes sense to configure NAT. I'll try it later and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I'm preparing the modifications and already have this question. If I use ACL 23 for NAT, which permits anything in 192.9.200.0/24. Will the other static NAT rules that I already configured still work? Or do i need to explicitly deny them in the ACL?

Comment: Those rules should work; they are for NAT the other way. Basically, they are static NAT table entries, but sourcing traffic from inside will create dynamic NAT table entries.

Answer (score 11):

You don't have NAT enabled (you don't have `ip nat outside` on Vl 20).

Without NAT, the ISP doesn't know how to route back to your 192.9.200.0 network.  If you NAT to the VLan 20 address, the ISP will be able to route back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is quit simple but your configuration is missing NAT overload rule . Which is used to translate private ip address to public ip address  , All internet outbound traffic  will use this NAT translation  configuration

`Router(config)# access-list 10 permit ip 192.9.200.0 255.25&.255.0 Any`
`Router(config) # ip nat inside source list 10 interface Ge0 0verlaod`

Futher to make it simple avoid vlan 10& Vlan 20  creation

`Router(config) int Ge0 Router(config) # ip address 81.246.66.67 255.255.255 Router(config) # ip nat  outside Router(config)# no shutdown`

`Router(config) # int Ge1 Router(config)# ip address 192.9.200.253 255.255.255.0 Router(config)# ip nat inside Router(config)no shutdown`

`Router(config) # ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 81.246.66.66`

**NAT overload rule for nat translation for outbound traffic inside to outside **.

`Router(config)# access-list 10 permit ip 192.9.200.0 255.25&.255.0 Any`

`Router(config) # ip nat inside source list 10 interface Ge0 0verlaod`